# How can I determine the current row index of a bookmarked element?

Tags: vba, ms-word, row

Let's assume I have an arbitrary bookmarked element in my Word document, e.g. a Form Field `myField`, in a table. How can I automatically determine the current table index and row index of that element?

Is there something like this?

```
ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("myField").tableIndex ' get table index
ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("myField").rowIndex   ' get row index
```

Comment: http://www.vbaexpress.com/forum/archive/index.php/t-27588.html might help

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't, because I have to programatically get the table/row index; so bookmarking the tables wouldn't help.